# How to fix this error which occured on 35. line of code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, pointers, vector

This is the [output with the error](https://ibb.co/XLMw9P9).

And this is my homework text:

> Think about a network that consists of nodes and one direction links.
>   Each node will be represented by a character and each link has an
>   integer cost value.

So when all nodes have only one link it works but when I include more than one links to one node it does not work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Node {
public:
    char nodeChar;
    int cost;

    Node(char nodeChar) {
        this->nodeChar = nodeChar;
    }

    vector<Node> nextNodes;

    void connect(Node &next, int cost) {
        next.cost = cost;
        this->nextNodes.push_back(next);
    }
};

int main() {
    Node A('A'), B('B'), C('C'), D('D');
    A.connect(C, 3); // A[0] = C
    C.connect(B, 4); // C[0] = B
    B.connect(A, 2); // B[0] = A
    C.connect(D, 5); // C[1] = D
    D.connect(B, 6); // D[0] = B

    int sum = 0;
    Node currentNode = A;

    while (sum < 15) {
        cout << currentNode.nodeChar;
        Node next = currentNode.nextNodes[0];
        currentNode = next;
        sum += next.cost;
    }

    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: presumably `currentNode.nextNodes` is empty so `currentNode.nextNodes[0]` is invalid

Comment: but i've created nextNodes in the class with connect function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
A.connect(C, 3);
```

`connect` takes the `next` node as a reference, but when it puts it into `nextNodes`, `nextNodes` makes a copy. That means that after `A.connect(C, 3);` and `C.connect(B, 4);`. The C in A is different from C and knows nothing of B. This copy of C has no nodes in `nextNodes`, so

```
Node next = currentNode.nextNodes[0];
```

ventures into undefined behaviour. In your case that behaviour is *it does not work.* Whatever that means.

Solution: A must contain a reference to C, not a copy of it. You are going to have to familiarize yourself with the use of pointers or reference wrappers because you cannot place references into a `vector`.